# Explain regular expression in Python

Tags: python, nlp, expression, regular-language

Can you help me to understand this code line by line please?

```
def word(w)
    pattern = re.compile(r'^[^aeiouAEIOU]+')

    if re.findall(r'[^aeiouAEIOU]y[^aeiouAEIOU]', w):
        pattern = re.compile(r'^[^aeiouAEIOUy]+')
        beginning = re.findall(pattern, word)
        w = pattern.sub('', w)
        w += str(beginning[0]) + 'ay'
        return w
```

For me this part is confusing :
[^aeiouAEIOU]y[^aeiouAEIOU]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the regular expression `[^aeiouAEIOU]y[^aeiouAEIOU]` we can break it down into:

- `[^aeiouAEIOU]` - not a vowel
- `y` - the letter 'y'
- `[^aeiouAEIOU]` - not a vowel

Specifically, `[aeiou]` would be a set of all lowercase vowels, so that matches on one character of "aeiou". The caret `^` means not, so `[^aeiou]` would match on any character other than a lower case vowel.

Therefore the regex matches the letter "y" with any character directly before and after it that is not a vowel.